# framework for mashup application

Tags: php, frameworks, mashup

I need to create a mashup application (uses many APIs to integrate different services in one). Just to be clear the difference between mashup and an web application that uses many APIs is that the mashup will also integrate ready widgets (UI), not only request an API.

Is there a framework with focus on mashup application (PHP is preferred)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not exactly what you looking for, but this may help:
http://elastic.io/ - this is a new tool designed for end users who want to create simple applications that tie together different services

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/ -  is a powerful composition tool to aggregate, manipulate, and mashup content from around the web

Answer (score 0):

A 'mashup' application as you describe isn't any different to any other application.

If you don't have a requirement for alot of code (but are mostly using web services etc.) then pick a lightweight framework.

Which one you pick will depend on you skill level.

Look at Laravel and Silex to start off with. Not sure why you are saying PHP Preferred, but if you are just starting out then I'd recommend looking at Rails too.